# Dialplan for ringing multiple extension

Tags: asterisk

how can i dial multiple extension in asterisk using dial command in round robin method?
I do not want to use queues.
I want to dial 3 extensions in round robin method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try dial sequentially all ramal or extensions that do you want like it:

```
exten => 111(start),1,Dial(SIP/YOUR_RAMAL,30,tT)
exten => 111,n,Dial(SIP/YOUR_RAMAL,30,tT)
exten => 111,n,Dial(SIP/YOUR_RAMAL,30,tT)
exten => 111,n,GotoIf($["${DIALSTATUS}" = "NOANSWER"]?start)
```

In this case we try call the first dial for 30 seconds if no answer he jump for the next, at the end if does not exist answer he jump to start again!

Comment: what happens if first extensions answer the call?

Comment: whether it will goes to the fourth line in your code or again it rings the second extension.